# Custom toggle function does not work with ng-click in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create the following in my Ionic app:

1. User gets to see a list of radio buttons
2. When user clicks item (for now only "Comparison" works), it automatically shows a follow-up question in a list
3. When user clicks on the question (found in the list dividers), the list with answers is toggled (in)visible.

For the first question this toggling works fine. However, for the second question I don't get it to work.

Is it a problem when I use the same function name "toggleList" in the "vizType" and "comparison" objects? Otherwise I have no clue why this does not work. Thanks!

**HTML code**

```
<ion-view title="Chartly" hide-back-button="true">
<ion-content>
    <ion-list ng-controller="questionsAnswersCtrl">
        <div ng-show="vizType.questionVisible">
          <div class="item item-divider item-icon-right" ng-click="vizType.toggleList()">
              1. VISUALIZATION TYPE
              <i class="icon ion-chevron-down" ng-show="!vizType.answersVisible"></i>
              <i class="icon ion-chevron-up" ng-show="vizType.answersVisible"></i>
              <span class="answer">{{ vizType.answer }}</span>
          </div>
          <div ng-show="vizType.answersVisible">
              <ion-radio ng-model="vizType.answer" ng-value="'Comparison'">Comparison</ion-radio>
              <ion-radio ng-model="vizType.answer" ng-value="'Distribution'">Distribution</ion-radio>
              <ion-radio ng-model="vizType.answer" ng-value="'Relationship'">Relationship</ion-radio>
              <ion-radio ng-model="vizType.answer" ng-value="'Composition'">Composition</ion-radio>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="comparison.questionVisible">
            <div class="item item-divider item-icon-right" ng-click="comparison.toggleList()">
                2. COMPARISON BETWEEN
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-down" ng-show="!comparison.answersVisible"></i>
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-up" ng-show="comparison.answersVisible"></i>
                <span class="answer">{{ comparison.answer }}</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="comparison.answersVisible">
                <ion-radio ng-model="comparison.answer" ng-value="'Time Periods'">Time Periods</ion-radio>
                <ion-radio ng-model="comparison.answer" ng-value="'Categories'">Categories</ion-radio>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-list>


</ion-content>
```

**JS code**

```
.controller('questionsAnswersCtrl', function($scope) {

/* VISUALIZATION TYPES */
$scope.vizType = {
    answersVisible: true,
    questionVisible: true,
    answer: ''
};

$scope.vizType.toggleList = function() {
    $scope.vizType.answersVisible = !$scope.vizType.answersVisible;
};

$scope.$watch('vizType.answer', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal, oldVal);

    if (newVal) {
        $scope.vizType.answersVisible = false;
    }

    if (newVal == 'Comparison' && newVal != oldVal) {
        $scope.comparison = {
            answersVisible: true,
            questionVisible: true
        };
    } else {
        $scope.comparison = {
            answersVisible: false,
            questionVisible: false
        };
    }
});



/* COMPARISON */
$scope.comparison = {
    answersVisible: false,
    questionVisible: false,
    answer: ''
};

$scope.comparison.toggleList = function() {
    $scope.comparison.answersVisible = !$scope.comparison.answersVisible;
};
})
```

Comment: I can't understand what's your desider behaviour... So I prepared a codepen   maybe it could help (http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/ZQwZZm)

Comment: For the second question (after answering Comparison), I also want to have the possibility to toggle the visibility of the answers when clicking on the question itself.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with $watch setting comparison.answersVisible to true. It seems that $watch is overruling the attempt of toggleList to set comparison.answersVisible to false. Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. Below you find the HTML and JS code for those who are interested.

**HTML code**

```
<ion-view title="Chartly" hide-back-button="true">
<ion-content>
    <ion-list ng-controller="questionsAnswersCtrl">

        <div ng-show="vizType.questionVisible">
          <div class="item item-divider item-icon-right" ng-click="vizType.toggleList()">
              1. VISUALIZATION TYPE
              <i class="icon ion-chevron-down" ng-show="!vizType.answersVisible"></i>
              <i class="icon ion-chevron-up" ng-show="vizType.answersVisible"></i>
              <span class="answer">{{ vizType.answer }}</span>
          </div>
          <div ng-show="vizType.answersVisible">
              <ion-radio ng-model="vizType.answer" ng-value="'Comparison'" ng-change="vizType.processAnswer('comparison')" name="vizType">Comparison</ion-radio>
              <ion-radio ng-model="vizType.answer" ng-value="'Distribution'" ng-change="vizType.processAnswer('distribution')" name="vizType">Distribution</ion-radio>
              <ion-radio ng-model="vizType.answer" ng-value="'Relationship'" ng-change="vizType.processAnswer('relationship')" name="vizType">Relationship</ion-radio>
              <ion-radio ng-model="vizType.answer" ng-value="'Composition'" ng-change="vizType.processAnswer('composition')" name="vizType">Composition</ion-radio>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="comparison.questionVisible">
            <div class="item item-divider item-icon-right" ng-click="comparison.toggleList()">
                2. COMPARISON BETWEEN
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-down" ng-show="!comparison.answersVisible"></i>
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-up" ng-show="comparison.answersVisible"></i>
                <span class="answer">{{ comparison.answer }}</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="comparison.answersVisible">
                <ion-radio ng-model="comparison.answer" ng-value="'Time Periods'" name="comparison">Time Periods</ion-radio>
                <ion-radio ng-model="comparison.answer" ng-value="'Categories'" name="comparison">Categories</ion-radio>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-list>


</ion-content>
```

**JS code**

```
.controller('questionsAnswersCtrl', function($scope) {

/* VISUALIZATION TYPES */
$scope.vizType = {
    answersVisible: true,
    questionVisible: true,
    answer: '',
    toggleList: function() {
        $scope.vizType.answersVisible = !$scope.vizType.answersVisible;
    },
    processAnswer: function(answer) {
        $scope.vizType.answersVisible = false;

        if (answer == 'comparison') {
            $scope.comparison.answersVisible = true;
            $scope.comparison.questionVisible = true;
        } else {
            $scope.comparison.answersVisible = false;
            $scope.comparison.questionVisible = false;
            $scope.comparison.answer = '';
        }
    }
};

/* COMPARISON */
$scope.comparison = {
    answersVisible: false,
    questionVisible: false,
    answer: '',
    toggleList: function() {
        $scope.comparison.answersVisible = !$scope.comparison.answersVisible;
    }
};
})
```